# How to remove duplicate lines within brackets in vim?

Tags: vim

I have json file that has duplicate values that I wish to remove using vim. Here is an example:

```
{
  { "greetings" : [
      "hello",
      "hello",
      "hola",
      "hola"
    ]
  }, ...
}
```

to

```
{
  { "greetings" : [
      "hello",
      "hola"
    ]
  }, ...
}
```

So far, I was able to successfully remove all duplicate lines expect those at the end. There is an extra ',' that breaks my matching and I end up with

```
{
  { "greetings" : [
      "hello",
      "hola",
      "hola"
    ]
  }, ...
}
```

Comment: are the duplicated lines adjacent to each other?

Comment: Yes. All duplicates are grouped together in new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since duplicated lines are adjacent to each other, you can use `\1` to match a string again, and use `,\?` to make the comma optional:

```
:%s/^\(.\+\),\?\n\1\n/\1\r/gc
```

If you need to limit the search and replace to certain blocks, you can use [`g/../`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) to match the block first:

```
:g/[\[^[\]*]/%s/^\(.\+\),\?\n\1\n/\1\r/g
```

Comment: @DJMcMayhem, thanks for the tip. I didn't know about the `\v` option

Comment: This is a good approach. However, the question was to limit the substitution to a block. The substitution solution you suggested will also remove all closing brackets. e.g. `}, }`

Comment: @Feras. sure. you can use `g/../` to match the block first. see updated solution.